# Using SED to replace multiple parts of string at once

Tags: sed

I have the following line in a file that I need to replace 2 parts of.  This is the original line:

```
'display min(min(sindex,lon=%lon1%,lon=%lon2%),lat=%lat1%,lat=%lat2%)'
```

I need to replace it with this:

```
'display amin(actualPrecip,lon=%lon1%,lon=%lon2%,lat=%lat1%,lat=%lat2%)'
```

I used regexr.com to generate this regex to match the 2 parts, but not sure what to do with it.  Basically I need to use sed to do an inplace replacement.

```
('display min\(min)|(\)\,)
```

That generated this on regexr.com:
'`display min(min`(sindex,lon=%lon1%,lon=%lon2%`),`lat=%lat1%,lat=%lat2%)'
So the first part needs to be replaced with `'display amin(` and 2nd match needs to be replaced with just a comma. Is there an easy way to do this using sed?

Cheers, Mike

Comment: I cleaned up most of your formatting, but I can't figure out what you were trying to show for the regexr.com result. Please put the formatted results between lines with three backticks, like the edits I made.

Comment: Are the quotes part of the file?

Comment: If you need to replace two parts, do it as two separate `s///` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it in PHP instead of a regular expression, it achieved the same results:

```
<?php
        exec("ls -b *.gs", $result);

        foreach($result as $filename) {
                echo "filename {$filename} \n";
                $data = file_get_contents($filename);
                $start = stripos($data, "display min(min(", 1);
                $replaced = false;

                if ($start !== false) {
                        $finish = $start + 16;
                        $data = substr_replace($data, "display amin(", $start, $finish - $start);
                        $start = stripos($data, "),", $finish+1);
                        $finish = $start+2;
                        $data = substr_replace($data, ",", $start, $finish - $start);
                        $replaced = true;
                }

                $start = stripos($data, "display max(max(", 1);

                if ($start !== false) {
                        $finish = $start + 16;
                        $data = substr_replace($data, "display amax(", $start, $finish - $start);
                        $start = stripos($data, "),", $finish+1);
                        $finish = $start+2;
                        $data = substr_replace($data, ",", $start, $finish - $start);
                        $replaced = true;
                }

                if ($replaced === true) file_put_contents($filename, $data);
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/min(min(sindex\([^)]*\))/amin(actualPrecip\1/' file
```

Use pattern matching and a back reference to format as desired.